# Using single characters for variable names in loops/exceptions

Tags: coding-style

I've had a couple of discussions with a co-worker about the use of single letter variable names in certain circumstances inside our codebase, at which we both disagree.

He favours more verbose naming convention for these, and I do not.

There are three scenarios in my opinion where I use single letter variable names:

- **Loops** - `i` `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... }`
- **Lambda expressions in C#** - `x/y/z`:  `.Where(x => x == 5)`
- **Exceptions** - `e`: `try { ... } catch(ExceptionType e) { /* usage of 'e' */ }`

These are the **only** scenarios where I would use it, and I obviously use more verbose naming conventions elsewhere.

My colleague put forward the following arguments for exceptions and loops:

- `i` - it doesn't mean anything.
- `e` - it's the most common letter in the English language. If you wanted to search the solution for exceptions, you'd find lots of undesired instances of `e`.

I accept these arguments, but have retorts that, if one does not know what `i` means in a for loop, then they probably shouldn't be a programmer. It's a very common term for loops and exceptions, as is `e`. I have also mentioned that, if one wanted, they could search for `catch` in the case of the exception.

I realise that this is subjective, but then, one could argue that coding standards are just that - opinions, albeit opinions by academics.

I would be happy either way, and will forward the results to him, but would rather that we (our company) continue to use a single coding standard, rather than have two developers with different opinions on what to use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, but perhaps more suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Paul R: Thanks! I have just re-raised it here - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/71710/using-single-characters-for-variable-names-in-loops-exceptions. This question can be flagged to be closed, but to be honest, I think it's still valid here on SO.

Comment: *If you wanted to search the solution for exceptions, you'd find lots of undesired instances of e.* Why would you search for instances of a type by guessing variable names?!

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: I also asked this question, and countered with 'search for `catch` instead`.

Comment: Whats wrong with just searching for `Exception`?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: The possibility (however remote) of finding custom exception types. Eg, `public class MyException : Exception { }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i doesn't mean anything`

Yes it does. It's the index in a for loop or counter.

`e is the most common letter in the English language. If you wanted to search the solution for exceptions, you'd find lots of undesired instances of e`

This just doesn't even make any sense. Why would you search for `e` if you wanted to find instances of `Exception`?

Serioulsy, I'd just laugh at anyone who came out with these arguments. *Everyone* knows what `i` and `e` represent in these scenarios. They are **universally accepted conventions**. It sounds to me like your colleague is just trying to be a smart-ass.

**Edit** - This question reminded me of [this wtf](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/CodeThatDocumentsItselfSoWellItDoesNotNeedComments.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

If the lexical scope of a variable is more than 20 or 25 lines, then the variable should probably not have a single letter name.  If a large number of variables in your code base have a lexical scope larger than 25 lines (or so), then your code base has a much bigger problem than can be dealt with by using a verbose naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Another exception to the rule that I apply is naming of exception variables that need to be thrown. For instance, the code should read:

```
Exception yourToys = new Exception(...);
throw yourToys;
```

or

```
Exception up_in_a_bucket = new Exception(...);
throw up_in_a_bucket;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a conversation with somebody about this.

I'm come to the opinion that, for operations that are a functional abstraction, using a "meaningful" name can be overstated.

For instance, in JavaScript:

```
myArrayOfNames.forEach ( function ( name ) { } );
myArrayOfNames.map ( function ( name ) { } );
myArrayOfNames.filter ( function ( name ) { } );
```

I generally use "each", "obj" or just "d" for these sorts of things, because I see these as course-grained abstractions. "name" really tells me nothing other than it's a name from an array of names.

Who cares? Because I've seen developers iterate reviews arguing about what is "meaningful". More than once.

So over the years, I gravitated towards settling it by saying, the operation is a functional abstraction (iteration) applied to a specific list of some kind. Reflect that language, and usage, in your code:

```
myUsefullyNamedArray.filter ( function ( d ) {
    return ( 'someval' in d ); 
} );
```