# Why to avoid using i, j in for loop

Tags: .net, coding-style

In many code reviews they suggest dont use i, j as variables..Is there any specific reason to avoid using i, j in for loop.

e.g

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++ )
{

}
```

Comment: who told that you should avoid them? it is the basic iterator variables even used in the conventions. they are perfect to use.

Comment: they say it because it is not following camel case naming conventions to declare a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802403/using-single-characters-for-variable-names-in-loops-exceptions

Comment: How can you camel case a single letter? :)

Comment: Are mentioned code reviews from the internet or maybe ones had at work? Because if the code review was made at work it may be a standard to that company to avoid i and j in loops; company coding styles usually override general conventions. On the other hand, relating to .net, you should try to use iterators instead of for-loops with indexes everytime is possible.

Comment: because it reminds them of their fortran days

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic guideline is to use variable names that are meaningful. `i` isn't very meaningfull, however, inside a for loop it often isn't a problem, when the scope of the for loop is really small. One letter variables for loop variables is very intuitive for most developers, and when that variable is only used in one or two lines, it isn't that big of a deal. When the scope gets bigger on the other hand, it gets harder to follow what `i` actually is. But than again, you should normally not have more than one line of code (just a method call) in a for loop anyway, to keep your code as readable as possible.

Still, even with a loop with a body of a single line, I would prefer a more meaningful name than `i`. For instance, what exactly does that `i` variable represent? If you can give it a more meaningfull name, such as `index` or `rowNumber`, you should do so. It makes your code more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If your variables have so other meaning than iterate an array or some other kind of data structure you should use a variable name that is more meaningful, otherwise it's OK to use i or j.

Answer (score 0):

One-letter names tend to convey no information about what they contain or represent. Using a short descriptive word (e.g. `row`, `attempt`, `element`, etc.) is usually a better choice.

Comment: This is exactly what they told me...But when it is simply a loop repetition variable..why not to use i , j...which is now in blood..why even i think of a name for that..

Comment: There is no such thing as a "[simple] loop repetition variable"; *everything* means *something*.